# Alpha texture quality problem (pixelated textures)

Tags: transparency, sculpting

So Im pretty new to blender and this question is probably very easy to solve. I am trying to use an alpha texture on a simple cube that measures 2m and have applied a multires modifier to and subdivided 7 times. In the attached picture you can se the alpha texture I am trying to use on the brush and the same texture applied to the object. The problem is the applied texture looks al pixelated and low quality and have no idea on how to fix this.

[image]

Comment: Your mesh is not detailed enough to be sculpted with so fine details. You could enable _Dyntopo_ to refine your mesh while sculpting. But be careful, this can go high poly very quickly.

Comment: Ok everyone I already solved this please don't rush to keep posting answers. So I had to add more geometry to my basic shape in order for it to work ( I added some loop cuts ) and that solved the issue. I appreciate everyone's help.